# type assertion to ma[string][]string after unmarshaling to map[string]interface{} fails

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Cannot assert the type `map[string][]string` after unmarshaling to `map[string]interface{}`. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/FGMEanuZrMx) is a small snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    M map[string][]string `json:"m"`
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"m":{}}`) //m will always exist but it might be empty or have some values. No difference if me is not empty, e.g. `{"m":{"s": ["abc"]}}`

    var test Test
    json.Unmarshal(b, &test) // This is fine, but for some reason I have to unmarshal to map[string]interface{}
    fmt.Println(test)

    var raw map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(b, &raw)
    test2 := Test{}
    test2.M = raw["m"].(map[string][]string) // error here
    fmt.Println(test2)
}
```

I get this error:

```
interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not map[string][]string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unmarshal json to an interface{}, the result is a tree composed of:

- map[string]interface{} for json objects,
- []interface{} for json arrays, and
- string, float64, bool, json.Number, or nil for values.

After you unmarshal. `raw["m"]` is a map[string]interface{}, whose values are []interface{}. Then you can assert each value to string:

```
for k,v:= range raw["m"].(map[string]interface{}) {
   for _,x:=range v.([]interface{}); {
      test2.M[k]=append(test2.M[k],x.(string))
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and you've already given my answer, just I'm not across this tree structure perhaps being built during the umarshaling, could you please add a reference for further details?

Comment: @mok The [json.Unmarshal documentation](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal) describes the structure.